# Android-VTS : running VTS failed with following error in Android 10

Tags: python, android

i did setup as mentioned in the AOSP https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-vts/#1
still i am seeing the error , also try installing manually same error is observed. let me know if any one know how to resolve

01-21 15:20:51 I/VtsPythonVirtualenvPreparer: Preparing python dependencies...
01-21 15:20:53 E/VtsPythonVirtualenvPreparer: Installing enum from PyPI failed.
01-21 15:20:59 E/VtsPythonVirtualenvPreparer: Installing enum from PyPI failed.
01-21 15:21:10 E/VtsPythonVirtualenvPreparer: Installing enum from PyPI failed.
01-21 15:21:45 E/VtsPythonVirtualenvPreparer: Installing enum from PyPI failed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace vts pip by pip of the system via "which pip" command. It's worked